# Play Scala - Have a POST method without JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I wanted to know if there were any ways to have a POST call on my Play framework REST API without any JSON in the call.

I'm making the API with the logic that if you create anything in the database, then you need to make a POST call, but yet I have this issue that occurs right when it hits the API :

```
Bad Request

        For request 'POST /promotions/add/user?userId=41375&promoId=24265'
[Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@a5de52b; line: 1, column: 0]]
```

Is there a way or I have to change the call in GET or make otherwise with userId and promoId in a JSON, which I would like to avoid.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you post your action code?

Comment: def addPromotionToUser(userId: Option[String], promoId: Option[String]): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { ... }

I ask nowhere for any JSON on the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have set any **content-type** in the request. Also check how the requests are handled within the action method like using `request.body.as<XXX>` etc. 
 
If your POST request is not using the json as the data payload, you may use a form to be bound from the request. In that case, make sure that you have set the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the request. Sometimes, it doesn't matter you set proper content type header in request. It all depends on how POST request is handled by the controller action methods/API endpoints.

Comment: Oh, that was just simply that, the content type in the call  -_- Well thank you very much ! It indeed works now ! :)